# Goroutines select with range loop

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

I want to spawn a goroutine to listen to two channels of type `chan int` and `chan os.Signal`. I want the behavior to be specific depending on what's received on either channels. Meaning some `os.Signal` may cause `os.exit()` and some may not, some `int` received through `chan int` may print a statement and some may call a function, so I need this gorountine to be always running since the behaviors are different. And I'd like this to be all handed by one function.

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to achieve this syntactically. It doesn't seem like I can have `range` loops inside of a `select` block nor does it seem like I can have a `select` block inside a `range` loop. I can't find any resource online on this. Can someone give me an example?

Comment: Could you provide a code sample (even if it's incomplete) that shows us what you're trying to figure out?  Even if it's pseudocode, it would still help and we'd have an easier time answering your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a [`select` statement](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements) in a `for` loop (this is one of the examples in the language spec).  Unlike a `for...range` loop, this will let you read from both channels.  It also won't automatically terminate if one of the channels closes.  When you [receive from a closed channel](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator), a closed channel is always ready to receive and always produces a zero value, and there is a two-valued form of it that tells you whether the channel is open or not.

Your function might loosely look like

```
func HandleStuff(numbers <-chan int, signals <-chan os.Signal) {
    var goingToExit bool
    for {
        select {
        case n := <-numbers:
            if n == 0 {
                fmt.Printf("zero\n")
            } else if n == 1 {
                goingToExit = true
            }
        case sig, ok := <-signals:
            if !ok { // the channel is closed
                return
            } else if goingToExit {
                os.Exit(0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks!